# Trailing zero as a result of snprintf

Tags: c, string, printf

Today I ran into a problem that I just can't get the hang of. Consider this code snippet:

```
static const char *LOG_MESSAGES[] = {"String1.", "A longer string 2.", "String 3"};
```

Somewhere in the `main()` function, I wrote:

```
printf("%s\n", LOG_MESSAGES[1]);//Prints "A longer string 2." as expected.
char rawLog[100] = {0};
printf("%s\n", rawLog);//Prints an empty string as expected.
snprintf(rawLog, 100, LOG_MESSAGES[1]);
printf("%s\n", rawLog);//Prints "A longer string 2.0". Adds a zero at the end.
```

I may be missing something obvoius, but this trailing zero just makes no sense to me. If I change

```
snprintf(rawLog, 100, LOG_MESSAGES[1]);
```

to

```
snprintf(rawLog, strlen(LOG_MESSAGES[1]), LOG_MESSAGES[1]);
```

the zero dissapears. Still, even with the size given as 100, `snprintf()` should stop at the end of `LOG_MESSAGES[1]`.

Where is this zero coming from?

Comment: last `'.'` rewrite to `'\0'`.

Comment: voting to close: the code in the question does not cause the issue (it transpired in comments that the bug was actually in different code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

As per the information received in comments, the **case 1** is the issue in this case.

---

In your case , both

```
 snprintf(rawLog, 100, LOG_MESSAGES[1]);                    //..........case 1
```

and

```
snprintf(rawLog, strlen(LOG_MESSAGES[1]), LOG_MESSAGES[1]); //..........case 2
```

are erroneous, considering the `LOG_MESSAGES[1]` string *may* contain some form of format specifier itself.

- **Case 1:**   you forgot the format string, like `%s`.
- **Case 2:**  Case 1, plus, you did not write the *entire string*. Remember, `strlen()` does not *count* the terminating null byte in the *size*. You needed `strlen(LOG_MESSAGES[1]) + 1` atleast, to write the *entire* string content, plus the null-terminator.

Comment: `snprintf(rawLog, strlen(LOG_MESSAGES[1]), LOG_MESSAGES[1]);` is dangerous and should never be done. You need to max at `rawLog`'s size, not potential input's size.

Comment: And same question as to LPs' answer: Why is it not possible to use `LOG_MESSAGES[1]` ***as*** a format with no format specifiers ?

Comment: Thanks. I have another 20 correct snpritfs in the same source file, yet I somehow missed that i forgot the format specifier. Still, your answer is correct and lets leave this for whoever needs it next.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I mean you can write `snprintf(rawLog, 100, "ABCD.");` can't you?

Comment: @Eregrith Sorry for misleading you, the actual string actually contains a format specifier. It is just that I replaced it with a more user friendly string in english for the sake of this question.

Comment: @Eregrith I agree with your second comment. It certainly can. It's just like we're _habituated_. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Solver Ahhhhh that settles it then! Phew I thought we had a big problem here

Comment: @SouravGhosh OP's comment clarified it. I agree though that you should **never** use any variable string (especially user input) in place of the format string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry sir, what did I miss?

Comment: `snprintf` write buffsize-1 character and  add `'\0'`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I can't find anything in the man saying these functions would (and should) write a `\0` after what they wrote.

Comment: **7.19.6.5 The snprintf function 2**  _output characters beyond the n-1st are
discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end
of the characters actually written into the array._

Comment: snprintf is **not** dangerous. It always appends a trailing null. (Unless you actually pass 0 as the buffer size)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I AM SO DUMB. I was mistakling `snprintf()` for `strncpy()`. MY bad. :(

Comment: @MattMcNabb Right, as i mentioned, I mistook it for `strncpy()` where you need `n+1` size to copy the `\0`. Updated answer.

Comment: @Eregrith I seem to be pretty distracted today. The original string did really DID NOT have a standard format specifier. This is the original string: "Naredba %1 za prijelaz %2." Is the shown behaviour expected (or possible) for this string? Again, sorry for misinforming.

Comment: @Solver The problem is `%2.` which is treated as a decimal number, thus writing it as `2.0`. For example `"Naredba %1. za prijelaz %2.."` will produce `"Naredba %1.0 za prijelaz %2.0."`

Comment: @Eregrith This would never occur to me. Thanks very much. I seem to have made quite a mess with this question :D. Just for my information: how would you make that string to produce "Naredba %1 za prijelaz %2."?

Comment: @Solver either use `%%` which prints a `%` : `"Naredba %%1 za prijelaz %%2."`, or use a simple format `"%s"` and your string as a parameter, as mentioned in the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

Correct it to

```
snprintf(rawLog, 100, "%s\n", LOG_MESSAGES[1]);
```

In your example you are using LOG_MESSAGES[1] as format, not as the text to be copied to rawlog.

Comment: Yes but why does `"A longer string 2."` produce such an error? It does not contain any `'%'` and is null-terminated. It's written as-is, with no need to use any other parameters.

Comment: I realized that as soon as I saw the now-deleted answer that snprintf without a format specifier copies the whole buffer.